# Reactive points being plotted incorrectly in geom_point graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

Hoping someone can help me out here as I'm having trouble figure it out. As you can see in the image below, Robert Woods is selected as the Round 2 Selection and Deebo Samuel is selected as the Round 1 Selection. What I really want is for Samuel's X value to be where Woods is, and vice versa.

[image: ggplot example]

I tried to create a new value in the drafted_players section called ovr_pick_num that would create the overall pick number dynamically, but that doesn't seem to be working. Currently, it seems like the graph is reading Woods as having a higher fpts_rank (or some value other than the one in ovr_pick_num), which is one of the outputs of the set_vor() function. Not sure if my calculation for ovr_pick_num is incorrect or the graph is reading the wrong value, but something's clearly wrong.

Hopefully this makes enough sense - please post any comments for any clarification needed. Here is the code for the Shiny app (the UI section can be ignored, but is needed to get the inputs necessary for the server section):

```
if(interactive()){

    ## load required packages
    library(shiny)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggrepel)
    library(dplyr)

    source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samhoppen/2020_FF_Analysis/master/Functions/set_vor.R")
    projections <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samhoppen/2020_FF_Analysis/master/Test_Data/Projections.csv")

    ui <- fluidPage(
        titlePanel("2020 Fantasy Football Draft Evaluator"),
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(id = "tPanel",style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 600px; position:relative;",
                         p(strong("Select draft settings")),
                         fluidRow(
                             column(6, selectInput(inputId = "league_size",
                                                   label = "Select league size",
                                                   choices = c("8", "10", "12", "14", "16"), selected = "12")),
                             column(6, selectInput(inputId = "draft_position",
                                                   label = "Select draft position",
                                                   choices = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"), selected = "1"))),
                         p(strong("Select roster spots")),
                         fluidRow(
                             column(6, numericInput(inputId = "starting_qbs",
                                                    label = "# of starting QBs",
                                                    value = 1,
                                                    min = 0,
                                                    max = 6)),
                             column(6, numericInput(inputId = "starting_rbs",
                                                    label = "# of starting RBs",
                                                    value = 2,
                                                    min = 0,
                                                    max = 6))),
                         fluidRow(
                             column(6, numericInput(inputId = "starting_wrs",
                                                    label = "# of starting WRs",
                                                    value = 3,
                                                    min = 0,
                                                    max = 6)),
                             column(6, numericInput(inputId = "starting_tes",
                                                    label = "# of starting TEs",
                                                    value = 1,
                                                    min = 0,
                                                    max = 6))),
                         fluidRow(
                             column(6, numericInput(inputId = "starting_flex",
                                                    label = "# of flex spots",
                                                    value = 1,
                                                    min = 0,
                                                    max = 6)),
                             column(6, numericInput(inputId = "starting_superflex",
                                                    label = "# of superflex spots",
                                                    value = 0,
                                                    min = 0,
                                                    max = 6))),
                         fluidRow(
                             column(6, numericInput(inputId = "starting_dsts",
                                                    label = "# of starting DSTs",
                                                    value = 1,
                                                    min = 0,
                                                    max = 6)),
                             column(6, numericInput(inputId = "starting_kickers",
                                                    label = "# of starting Ks",
                                                    value = 1,
                                                    min = 0,
                                                    max = 6))),
                         p(strong("4. Draft your team!")),
                         uiOutput(outputId = "draftUI")
            ),
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("draftPlot"))


        )
    )

    server <- function(input, output) {

        total <- reactive(input$starting_qbs + input$starting_rbs + input$starting_wrs + input$starting_tes + input$starting_flex +
                              input$starting_superflex + input$starting_dsts + input$starting_kickers)
        output$draftUI <- renderUI({
            count <- total()
            list <- seq(count)
            list <- lapply(list, function(x) selectInput(paste0("draft_pick_",x),
                                                         paste0("Round ", x, " Selection"),
                                                         c("Select player" ="", final_vor_table()$player)))


            tagList(list)

        })


        vor_table <- reactive({
            default_baseline <- c(QB = 15, RB =72, WR = 90, TE = 30, K = 6)

            set_vor(projections,
                    vor_baseline = default_baseline,
                    vor_var = "fpts")})

        final_vor_table <- reactive({
            vor_table() %>% 
                arrange(desc(fpts_vor))
        })

        draft_picks <- reactive({
            paste0('draft_pick_',1:total()) %>% sapply(function(x) input[[x]])
        })

        drafted_players <- reactive({

            is_even <- function(x) x %% 2 == 0
            lg_sz <- as.numeric(input$league_size)
            draft_pos <- as.numeric(input$draft_position)


            new_vor_table <- final_vor_table() %>% 
                filter(player %in% draft_picks()) 

            new_vor_table %>% 
                mutate(round = seq.int(nrow(new_vor_table)),
                       ovr_pick_num = if_else(is_even(round), 
                                              ((round * lg_sz) - draft_pos + 1),
                                              ((round -1) * lg_sz) + draft_pos))
        })


        output$draftPlot <- renderPlot({
            req(final_vor_table(), draft_picks(), drafted_players())

            ggplot() +
                geom_smooth(data = final_vor_table(),
                            aes(x = final_vor_table()$fpts_rank, y = final_vor_table()$fpts_vor),
                            color = "firebrick",
                            linetype = "dashed",
                            size = 1,
                            method = "lm",
                            formula = y ~ poly(x, 10),
                            se = F) +
                geom_point(data = drafted_players(),
                           aes(x = drafted_players()$ovr_pick_num, y = drafted_players()$fpts_vor)) +
                geom_text_repel(data = drafted_players(),
                                aes(x = drafted_players()$ovr_pick_num, y = drafted_players()$fpts_vor, label = drafted_players()$player))
        })

    }
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your code produces warnings and errors before even beginning on the initial issue: `new_vor_table` is *empty* when you try to use it in the `drafted_players` data reactive. Have you tried to smooth this out? The problem is that `seq.int(0)` produce a length-2 vector `[1] 1 0`; I suggest you need `seq_len(nrow(...))` which will produce length 0 when you have 0 rows.

Comment: @r2evans I hadn''t tried to solve that issue yet - I put the req(final_vor_table(), draft_picks(), drafted_players()) in there so that the plot just doesn't appear without a value in one of the drafted_players options, but your seq_len() suggestion fixed that, so thanks! That said, this doesn't solve the original issue I was having. Any thoughts on how the players appearing incorrectly may get fixed?

Comment: No thoughts ... it's a bit more than I can look at now. I suggest, though, that you explain why you think the points are swapped: without looking at the raw data, it is not obvious to me (from a data/shiny standpoint).

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the help anyway, @r2evans!